# Order of parameters to foldright and foldleft in scala

Tags: scala

Why does the `foldLeft` take

```
f: (B, A) => B
```

and foldRight take

```
f: (A, B) => B
```

`foldLeft` could have been written to take `f: (A, B) => B.`
I am trying to understand the reasoning for the difference in the order of parameters.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's supposed to show you the direction of the aggregation.  FoldLeft aggregates from left to right, so you can imagine the accumulator B as bunching up stuff on the left side as it approaches each A:

If you have something like:

```
Vector(1,2,3,4,5).foldLeft(0)((b,a) => b + a)
```

Then you get this behavior

```
 B    ...As...
---------------
(0), 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
(0+1),  2, 3, 4, 5
(0+1+2),   3, 4, 5
(0+1+2+3),    4, 5
(0+1+2+3+4),     5
(0+1+2+3+4+5)
```

FoldRight, on the other hand, aggregates things from the right side.  So if you have something like:

```
Vector(1,2,3,4,5).foldRight(0)((a,b) => a + b)
```

Then you get this behavior

```
  ...As...     B
-----------------
1, 2, 3, 4, 5 (0)
1, 2, 3, 4, (5+0)
1, 2, 3,  (4+5+0)
1, 2,   (3+4+5+0)
1,    (2+3+4+5+0)
    (1+2+3+4+5+0)
```

Answer (score 0):

@dhg already provided a great answer.  My example illustrates an interesting subtlety: namely, that sometimes the the order in which the initial 
value is passed to the given function matters. So I figured I'd post this on the off chance someone 
is interested in  cases where foldRight can behave differently than foldLeft
with the same initial value, same function, and same input list.

Consider the exponentiation below:

```
   def verbosePower(base:Double, exp:Double) = { 
        println(s"base=$base / exp=$exp") ; 
        math.pow(base, exp) 
   }
   var X =  List(2.0,3).foldLeft(1.0) (verbosePower)
   System.out.println("x:" + X);

   X =  List(2.0,3).foldRight(1.0) (verbosePower)
   System.out.println("x:" + X);
```

the output and result from foldLeft is:

```
base=1.0 / exp=2.0
base=1.0 / exp=3.0
X: Double = 1.0
```

the output and result from foldRight is:

```
base=3.0 / exp=1.0
base=2.0 / exp=3.0
X: Double = 8.0
```

Comment: in short, this property called 'commutativity', so for `pow`, which is non-commutative , `foldLeft` and `foldRight` are different. And also `reduce(verbosePower)` called on parallel collection won't give a stable result.

Comment: @dk14 nice mathematical summary of what's going on.